# Google Plus Equivalent to Facebook Like Box

Tags: facebook, google-plus

I have just been testing out the [facebook like box](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) and was wondering if there was a google plus feature like it. Help would be mutch appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for Google+ page badge.
For documentation from Google please visit:
[Google+ Badge](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/badge/)

Answer (score 2):

The Google +1 Button!

http://www.google.com/+1/button/

http://www.google.com/intl/en/webmasters/+1/button/index.html?utm_source=b2cp1&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=p1

Answer (score 0):

This tool here is awesome: http://widgetsplus.com/
It gives you the possibility to create a widget including your newsfeed, follow button,...